# Relative path to your project directory

Tags: ruby

In my Ruby project I am using a mess of things like moving and editing files on several remote boxes and I really need something like a relative path to my root project directory. I have many processing folders which are used in many methods.

Right now I have paths hardcoded, but that makes me unhappy.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can get current directory (directory of current file) with this

```
File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

You can then join it with relative path to the root

```
File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../../') # add proper number of ..
```

Or you can use `expand_path` to convert relative path to absolute.

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

Or you can **calculate** relative path between two dirs.

```
require 'pathname'; 
puts Pathname.new('/').relative_path_from(Pathname.new('/some/child/dir/')).to_s
# => ../../..
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: The certain problem i faced is following -  

    FileUtils.chdir("\\\\someRemoteIp\\somedir")
    FileUtils.cp(filename, "local_box_drive\\folder")

then i need to extract some data from the file which is in the root of project

i have to do 

    FileUtils.chdir("E:\\folder\\folder\\my_project_folder")
    my_method(local_file_in_root_project_folder)

If i will run such code on some other box, it will fail, i need 

    FileUtils.chdir("E:\\folder\\folder\\my_project_folder")

substituted to some relative expression that will bring me to my project root folder

Comment: Do you have project folder in different locations on different boxes?

Comment: I need to be able to run the project on several boxes, so there should be no paths mapped to hard drives when making operations with files in project dir.

Comment: i need somethuing like RAILS_ROOT or Rails.root

Comment: Can't you set that env var in the main script, or upon invocation? Like `SCRIPT_ROOT=/my/dir ruby script.rb`.

Answer (score 33):

```
__dir__
```

Since Ruby 2, you can simply use Kernel-function `:__dir__` to get the absolute directory-path of the current file. So, to give an example, you could set a constant ROOT_DIR at the start of your project in the (config.rb, environments.rb, constants.rb, or whatever you call it).

See [Ruby Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__)

Comment: This is what I use presently, it's quite short and thus nice. I also keep a constant internally in a project, to keep track of it; and sometimes also a method that will return the path to the base directory, if the user is able to designate and overrule it (e. g. sometimes you may have to do so, such as when you are in a restricted environment like on campus, or when distributions such as debian split up components of ruby by default - debian uses some strange ruby paths).

Answer (score 1):

```rb
ROOT_DIR = File.expand_path(".")
```

- you can call it from any sub-script, it will resolve to project root dir