# How to make the path generic (RUBY)?

Tags: ruby, watir

This is how I am changing the directory path to the download folder.

```
Dir.chdir("C:/Users/abcd/Downloads/")
```

But this specific to a user. Is there is any way to make it more general?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416578/relative-path-to-your-project-directory
Is the best I can do without being able to see your attempted code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative path to your project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416578/relative-path-to-your-project-directory)

Answer (score 2):

Use `home` method for **Dir**

```
Dir.chdir(Dir.home + '/Downloads')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `"C:/Users/abcd/Downloads/"` looks like the user directory for user *abcd* on windows. So I think this is a windows related question.

The `Dir.home` on my Windows-PC is `U:/`, not the user-directory.

But you can make use of `ENV`:

```
Dir.chdir(File.join(ENV['USERPROFILE'], 'Downloads'))
```

Just to be aware of: This changes the directory for the rest of your script. There is also a [block-version of `Dir.chdir`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10148325/676874).